# c programming, not getting proper value of long double

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>            
#include <float.h>        

int main () {      
    printf("storage size of long double %d \n", sizeof(long double));  
    printf("minimum long double positive value of %e \n", LDBL_MAX); 
    printf("maximum long double positive value of %e \n", LDBL_MIN); 
    printf("Precision value of %d", LDBL_DIG);        
    return 0;     
}
```

Here's the output

```
Success time: 0 memory: 2160 signal:0    

storage size of long double 12     

maximum long double positive value of -nan     

minimum long double positive value of -0.000000e+00   

Precision value of 18


float   4 byte  1.2E-38 to 3.4E+38  6 decimal places        
double  8 byte  2.3E-308 to 1.7E+308    15 decimal places        
long double 10 byte 3.4E-4932 to 1.1E+4932  19 decimal places
```

I am getting the right value for `float` and `double` but not with `long double`; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using the C# tag?

Comment: which tag should i use for this Question

Comment: @PvVimalNair the tag that fits the question. C

Comment: Your main problem here is that you don't compile your program with (enough) warnings enabled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `L` flag (`%Le`) to signify that you pass `long double`:

```
printf("minimum long double positive value of %Le \n", LDBL_MAX);
printf("maximum long double positive value of %Le \n", LDBL_MIN);
```

Otherwise the original code gets part of the `long double` from the stack and interprets it as `double` which clearly becomes a mess.

Comment: send me full code, tried this one but not getting proper value.

Comment: @PvVimalNair: What value do you get, what value would you expect? Come on, that's debugging 101, really. I get `1.189731e+4932` / `3.362103e-4932`, which looks good to me.

Comment: @PvVimalNair: And while we're at it, if you're printing the result of `sizeof` (or any `size_t`, really), you should be using `%zu`, since `size_t` is not guaranteed to have the same width as an `int`, and is unsigned.

Comment: i am getting the same value, But this is the real answer long double '10 byte 3.4E-4932 to 1.1E+4932 19 decimal places

Comment: @PvVimalNair: What makes you think that'd be the output to expect? **On which platform / compiler?** 10 byte, *really*? And have you ever heard of rounding?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm  ... this is the link bro please see and let me know if you found something.. and i am using online compiler ideone.com

Comment: @PvVimalNair : 10 bytes might have been true for old DOS programs which didn't require any alignment. On any modern processor size of `long double` is still 10 bytes but it has to be aligned to either 4 or 8 bytes, so the `sizeof()` operator should return 12 or 16. Regarding the compiler - ideone.com is just kind of emulator and it may miss lot of standard stuff, including the formatting characters, correct type alignment and things like that. Use real compiler to get real results.

Comment: @PvVimalNair: Drop those online tutorials **right now**. They are not good for your health. All that the C language actually guarantees for `long double` is a value range of no less than 1E-37 to 1E+37, and no less than that of `double`. The **only** authority on these things is [the C standard itself](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Which, by the way, also allows for 128-bit `long double` *on platforms that support it*. Your tutorial is chock full of invalid assumptions, like two's complement, 8-bit `char` etc., and obviously not recent (no mention of `long long`).

Comment: ok  guys thank you very much, can you tell me any good compiler

Comment: @PvVimalNair: Nothing wrong with your compiler, it's the tutorial that's broken. (Most are, actually.)

Comment: one more thing what is %Le ?

Comment: @PvVimalNair: Please **do** read [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) on functions you're using. (The table halfway down the page. Pay attention to the rightmost column.)